# remove part of query in url with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following url:

`http://example.com/directory/proc.php?email=a@b.com&link=http://example.org`

The value in the "link" variable will always have http:// or https:// and i would like to strip it from the url.

So I would end up with:

`http://example.com/directory/proc.php?email=a@b.com&link=example.org`

Comment: does the code below answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^((.+&)?link=)(https?://)(.+)$
RewriteRule (.*) /$1?%1%4 [NC,L,R]
```